# How to improve this script and better make a "character cycling" effect?

Tags: javascript, html, animation

I made this script a while back to give my title this effect which *works* just not well. For a preview for the effect in question, see: https://ex0tic-python.github.io/
The code for it is rather bad and I haven't been able to find a workaround to using individual h1 tags to select each character individually. Is there a better way of doing this? The effect should look the same as it does currently, just wondering on how to touch up the current code. Any help is appreciated

This is the current code for the website you saw above:
HTML for the title

```html
<header>
                <h1 class="head_char_1">W</h1> <h1 class="head_char_2">e</h1> <h1 class="head_char_3">l</h1> <h1 class="head_char_4">c</h1>
                <h1 class="head_char_5">o</h1> <h1 class="head_char_6">m</h1> <h1 class="head_char_7">e</h1> <h1 style="white-space: pre;"> </h1>
                <h1 class="head_char_8">T</h1> <h1 class="head_char_9">o</h1> <h1 style="white-space: pre;"> </h1> <h1 class="head_char_10">M</h1>
                <h1 class="head_char_11">y</h1> <h1 style="white-space: pre;"> </h1> <h1 class="head_char_12">W</h1> <h1 class="head_char_13">e</h1>
                <h1 class="head_char_14">b</h1> <h1 class="head_char_15">s</h1> <h1 class="head_char_16">i</h1> <h1 class="head_char_17">t</h1>
                <h1 class="head_char_18">e</h1> <h1 class="head_char_19">!</h1>
</header>
```

CSS that affects this HTML (Still in process of touching it up, ignore any weird stuff)

```css
.flex_main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    color: #03fc18;
    background-color: #000000;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: Consolas;

    min-height: 74vh;
    margin: auto;
}

.flex_main header {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    display: flex;
}
```

JS for the title

```js
const titleTag = document.querySelector("header");
let charStr = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890~`!@#$%^&*()-_=+[{]}|;:',<.>/?";
const charArr = Array.from(charStr);

function randRange(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

function cycChar(charClass, endChar, duration) {

    function cyc() {
        const char = titleTag.querySelector(charClass);
        char.textContent = charArr[randRange(0, 101)];
    }

    function endCyc(inter) {
        clearInterval(inter);
        const char = titleTag.querySelector(charClass);
        char.textContent = endChar;
    }

    const cycCharInter = setInterval(cyc, 100);
    setTimeout(endCyc, duration, cycCharInter);
}

let finalCharsStr = "WelcomeToMyWebsite!";
const finalChars = Array.from(finalCharsStr);

const durationArr = [1, 1.2, 1.7, 2, 2.1, 2.7, 2.9, 3, 3.5, 4]

for (let i = 0; i <= 19; i++) {
    cycChar(".head_char_" + String(i+1), finalChars[i], durationArr[randRange(0, 9)] * 1000)
}
```